# Finding all other workstations on the network

Tags: networking, command-line, ifconfig

at my home I have both workstations directly use Ethernet cables to connect to router, and also a few laptops/mobile devices that connect to wifi. Is there a command in linux to see list of all devices accessing wifi/network? Thanks in advance, sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open your terminal and type this

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

then type as

```
sudo nmap -sP 192.168.0.1-254
```

so it will search all the devices from the range of 192.168.0.1 – 192.168.0.254 .

Hope that helps .

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to detect all devices in a IPv6 supported network is to ping the ip6-allnodes
address via ping6 like this

`ping6 -c 2 ff02::1%eth0`

all ipv6 capable devices will answer to that ping

Comment: nice , I am sure it will help in future.

Answer (score 0):

`nmap -sP 192.168.0.0/24` (where 192.168.0.0/24 - your subnet). If you need other scan method, not ping - read `man nmap`.